# Meter los valores recibidos en Base de datos en un input según su valor PHP

Tags: php

Explico: Mi intención es las 5 inserciones a bd tienen un valor que inserté previamente, pues quiero devolverle al usuario esos valores, para que los pueda modificar.

Adjunto código:

**PHP**

```
CONSULTA: SELECT * FROM inn_document_treballador WHERE tr_id_treballador=$trp_operario AND mes_semana_anio=$semesanio ORDER BY tr_piel_id ASC LIMIT 5



   $query_con = "SELECT * FROM inn_document_treballador WHERE tr_id_treballador=$trp_operario AND mes_semana_anio=$semesanio ORDER BY tr_piel_id ASC LIMIT 5";
   $ress=$bd->ejecutar($query_con);
   while($row = $ress->fetch_assoc()) {
     $tr_fase_lunes = $row['tr_fase_lunes'];
    }

            echo "<tr>";
          for ($l=0; $l<5; $l++){
              echo "<td><input type='text' id='dia_lunes_$l' name='tr_dia_lunes_$l' value='$flunes'></td>";
              echo "<td><input type='number' min='0' id='tr_fase_lunes_$l' name='tr_fase_lunes_$l' value='$tr_fase_lunes'>
</td>";
          }
```

[image: FRONTEND]
[image: BD]

Con esto no me introduce nada, ya que pasa 5 valores
Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con esto:

```php
$query_con = "SELECT * FROM inn_document_treballador WHERE tr_id_treballador = $trp_operario AND mes_semana_anio = $semesanio ORDER BY tr_piel_id ASC LIMIT 5";
$ress=$bd->ejecutar($query_con);
$contador = 0;
echo "<tr>";
while($row = $ress->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<td><input type='text' id='dia_lunes_$contador' name='tr_dia_lunes_contador' value='$flunes'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='number' min='0' id='tr_fase_lunes_$contador' name='tr_fase_lunes_$contador' value='$row['tr_fase_lunes']'></td>";
    $contador++;
}
```

de este modo haces lo que pretendes dentro del bucle directamente, incrementando la variable `$contador` en cada pasada, partiendo de 0.

Comment: Ya modifique con imágenes y todo @masterguru

Comment: Te añadi la consulta arriba @masterguru, pero me devuelve 5

Comment: Vale, a ver, para empezar, eso son filas de una sola columna, y en el `echo` que has puesto en tu pregunta lo intentas poner todo en columnas, sin separarlo en filas, por lo tanto te saldran 5 columnas de golpe si ejecutas mi codigo.  Si quieres verlo en filas debes poner un `<tr>` antes del `<td>`  y un `</tr>` despues del `</td>` en el echo de mi respuesta.

Comment: Actualizado @masterguru

Comment: He actualizado mi respuesta, mira a ver si ahora si (pero lo dudo, porque no se de donde viene el $flunes y mucho me temo que de otro bucle que no enseñas en la pregunta y se va a repetir todo el rato)